# Nested CSS grid and overflow-y

Tags: css, overflow, css-grid

I'm building a chat application (imagine WhatsApp Web) where I have a scrolling content of messages and where always an input field is visible at the bottom.
For the sake for this question, I simplified the desired working behavior to this snippet:

```html
<html lang="en" style="height: 100%">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>
  <body style="height: 100%; margin: 0">
    <div
      style="
        display: grid;
        height: 100%;
        grid-template-rows: [messages] 1fr [input] 50px;
      "
    >
      <div style="grid-row-start: messages; overflow-y: auto">
        <div style="height: 1000px; width: 100px; background-color: red">
          messages
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="grid-row-start: input; background-color: yellow">input</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the example above, the content is scrollable and the yellow bar is always visible.
But as soon as the design is getting more complex (more layout around, also using CSS grids) the yellow bar is pushed down. So far, I could not figure out the reason for it. Here is an example with a surrounding grid:

```html
<html lang="en" style="height: 100%">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>
  <body style="height: 100%; margin: 0">    
    <div style="display: grid; height: 100%; grid-template-rows: [chat] 1fr"><!--<--added level-->
      <div style="grid-row-start: chat; height: 100%">
        <div
          style="
            display: grid;
            height: 100%;
            grid-template-rows: [messages] 1fr [input] 50px;
          "
        >
          <div style="grid-row-start: messages; overflow-y: auto; height: 100%">
            <div style="height: 1000px; width: 100px; background-color: red">
              messages
            </div>
          </div>
          <div style="grid-row-start: input; background-color: yellow">
            input
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried to pass down the 100% height down but it didn't help either for the nested case. I also tried to use 100vh.
My goal is to avoid using `calc()` to reduce complexity and I also can't use a fixed height for the "messages" part.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the style of the first div after the body from: `grid-template-rows: [chat] 1fr;` to `grid-template-rows: [chat] 100%;` :

```html
<html lang="en" style="height: 100%">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>
  <body style="height: 100%; margin: 0">    
    <div style="display: grid; height: 100%; grid-template-rows: [chat] 100%"><!--<--added level-->
      <div style="grid-row-start: chat; height: 100%">
        <div
          style="
            display: grid;
            height: 100%;
            grid-template-rows: [messages] 1fr [input] 50px;
          "
        >
          <div style="grid-row-start: messages; overflow-y: auto; height: 100%">
            <div style="height: 1000px; width: 100px; background-color: red">
              messages
            </div>
          </div>
          <div style="grid-row-start: input; background-color: yellow">
            input
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But adding a fixed position defeats the purpose of having the grid layout IMO. Also the scrollbar should only span the height of the messages box.

Comment: Ah ok I understand, I found the issue and edited my demo please take a look and tell me if this is what you want